# Unable to invoke function as parameter in bash

Tags: bash

Team,

I am unable to invoke functions as parameter while calling the script that contains that function. Can you please hint what am I missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
if declare -f "$1" > /dev/null
then
  "$@"
else
  echo "$1 is not a defined function" >&2
  exit 1
fi

gfc() {
TEST_PERF_CLASS="GFC"
K8S_Node_Name=("10.1" "10.2" "10.3")
#declare -a K8S_Node_Name=("10.1" "10.2" "10.3")
if ([ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "DFC" ] || [ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "GFC" ]) && [ "$K8S_Node_Name" != "ALLCORDONED" ]; then
    for node in "${K8S_Node_Name[@]}"; do
      echo "$node"
      done
elif ([ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "DFC" ] || [ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "GFC" ]) && [ "$K8S_Node_Name" = "ALLCORDONED" ]; then
  echo "CORDONED"
else
    printf "Invalid NODE\n"
fi
}

dfc() {
TEST_PERF_CLASS="DFC"
K8S_Node_Name=("11.1" "110.2" "110.3")
if ([ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "DFC" ] || [ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "GFC" ]) && [ "$K8S_Node_Name" != "ALLCORDONED" ]; then
    for node in "${K8S_Node_Name[@]}"; do
      echo "$node"
      done
elif ([ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "DFC" ] || [ "$TEST_PERF_CLASS" = "GFC" ]) && [ "$K8S_Node_Name" = "ALLCORDONED" ]; then
  echo "CORDONED"
else
    printf "Invalid NODE\n"
fi
```

```
> bash bash-call-function.sh gfc
```

output expected:

```
10.1
10.2
10.3
```

Actual:

`gfc is not a defined function`

Comment: You haven't defined the functions yet when you run `declare -f "$1"`. The script is evaluated from top to bottom, *including* function definitions.

Comment: It would help to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "before declaration:"
type myfunc

myfunc() { echo "foo"; }

echo "after declaration:"
type myfunc
```

It prints the following:

```
before declaration:
./functest: line 4: type: myfunc: not found
after declaration:
myfunc is a function
myfunc () 
{ 
    echo "foo"
}
```

You can't call a function before it is declared; all you have to do is move your function declarations to the top of your file.